# How to structure a large program where multiple sections need to update the same variables

Tags: python, structure

I’m relatively new to python and I’m writing a program for my own interest that will simulate the evolution of plants. This involves a range of lists to hold genotype and phenotype data that need to be manipulated throughout.

What is the best way of logically breaking the code up into smaller chunks? I need to make a lot of changes to the variables throughout; I was going to use functions but would need to make all the lists global in many of the functions which I believe is not good practice.

The other option is to collapse all of the code back into the main program loop. But this would destroy the relative simplicity of the main program structure and clutter it with all the detailed manipulations of all the variables.

Is there a better way? I would prefer to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: From "use functions" it does not follow that you "would need to make all the lists global"; they could be parameters (possibly packaged into `self`).

Comment: Abstract your lists of data into data object(s), your program structure into a workflow object, and keep as much of your functional code as functions that accept data objects and can be unit tested as possible. Imo.

Comment: @Davis Herring. Perhaps I should read up more on objects and object related programming. But I can't see the advantage of passing the variables into the function changing them and then passing the variables out again as this appears to be just a long winded way of achieving global variables

Comment: @CJR well it sounds interesting, let me investigate. Hopefully this avenue of approach will not lead to a lot of complexity?

Comment: @Slarty: Global variables impair thread-safety, use by multiple clients (_e.g._, for some "sub-evolution" study), and human analysis (since _any_ code anywhere might use them).  Being more explicit ("long-winded") is sometimes a good thing.

Comment: I would highly suggest looking at pandas dataframes rather than a collection of lists

Comment: @Davis Herring Perhaps I am missing something here. It would seem to me that any function in my program could adjust the "Global variables" by passing them in and out as parameters. Or is there some subtlety of perspective or context that I am over looking?

Comment: @Slarty: Most functions wouldn't have any reference to those objects if they weren't global, so how would they modify them or pass them to something that did?

Comment: @David Herring this will only be running as a stand alone on my laptop so in one sense I can give any reference to any procedure. Are you (effectively) saying that by making the process to access the global variable more "fiddly" by passing them in and passing them out again that it will make it less likely that I will make a mistake?

Comment: @Slarty: You _can_ pass anything anywhere within code that you write, but you wouldn't have asked the question if you thought that its quality was independent of such choices.  It's hard to see with trivial programs, but there's no point in practicing an approach that would generalize so poorly even to your stated project.  You might, at the start, have to take it on authority that organizing your data and algorithms is worthwhile--so worthwhile, in fact, that simply having no (non-constant) globals at all (they can all go in `main`) will improve your code significantly.

Comment: @David Herring thanks for your answer. Yes you are right. The main problem is that my programming skills are a bit rusty. I can see that global is not good, but I will have to accept for the time being that passing the variables in and out is the way to go.  
 Hopefully it will start to become clearer as I am writing it.

Comment: The idea is that if you have 10 data structures in variables now youd make a MyDataObject that holds all of them and then just pass that one thing around. You can even put common data manipulation functions into your data class so you dont reuse code in different analysis functions. This reduces complexity, it doesn't increase it

Comment: @CJR Yes I see what you're saying. Seems like the way to go if you have a load of data. I will think about it as I'm already half way through designing the thing and I'm not familiar with any MyDataObject syntax. Bit of a judgement call.